# serialize and deserialize from flatbuffers to and from bytearray

Tags: java, serialization, flatbuffers

hi stackoverflow community :)

i want create a flatbuffers object in java which i can serialize to a byte array,
and later deserialize back in the java object. i work the first time with flatbuffers
and i can't initialised a java object. my way step by step:

1. write a scheme
2. compile this with the flatbuffers compiler into a java class
3. import the flatbuffers class from github
4. try to build a java object

Here is my code for step 4:

```
FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder(1);
int str = fbb.createString("Dummy");
Monster.startPerson(fbb);
Monster.addName(fbb, str);
int p = Person.endPerson(fbb);
```

Maybe someone can post a simple example to creating a flatbuffers object, and how to serialize and deserialize to and from bytearray?

Hope for an answer and best regards,

Paul

http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a answer on the google group page:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flatbuffers/FZBDMd9m0hE

Comment: How would you de-serialize it from byte array to FlatBuffer. Answer on this page doesn't cover de-serializing case.

Answer (score 3):

Serialize

```
FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder();
int str = fbb.createString("MyMonster");
Monster.startMonster(fbb);
Monster.addName(fbb, str);
int mon = Monster.endMonster(fbb); 
fbb.finish(mon);   
byte[] data = fbb.sizedByteArray();
```

Deserialzie

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
Monstermonster monster = Monster.getRootAsMonster(buff);
System.out.println(monster.name());
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `fbb.sizedByteArray()` does not work due to missing `fbb.finish()` call. See my answer.

Comment: Ah! I forgot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider you have the following FlatBuffers schema:

```
table ServiceException {
    message:string;
}
```

After compiling this schema with `flatc` to generate Java classes, you can create a `ServiceException` instance and convert it into a `byte[]` as follows:

```
FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder();
int messagePosition = fbb.createString("something bad happened");
int serviceExceptionPosition = ServiceException.createServiceException(fbb, messagePosition);
fbb.finish(serviceExceptionPosition);
byte[] outputBytes = fbb.sizedByteArray();
```

Next, you convert the generated `outputBytes` back into a `ServiceException` instance:

```
ByteBuffer inputByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(outputBytes);
ServiceException serviceException = ServiceException.getRootAsServiceException(inputByteBuffer);
```

Comment: .sizedByteArray() instead of .byteBuffer() saved my day :) Thanks!